# Display all the sub-categories in multiple <ul> tag

Tags: magento-1.9, category, navigation, category-tree

I have one main Category (**View All Inventory**) under which I have around 76 sub-categories. Right now it prints out all the 76 sub-categories in a single `<ul>` tag.

```
<?php $_menu = $this->getHtml('level-top') ?>
<?php if($_menu): ?>
<div class="nav-container">
    <ul id="nav">
        <?php echo $_menu ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

I would like to somehow divide all those subcategories equally and display them in multiple `<ul>` tag so the drop down menu spreads horizontally across the page instead of displaying them in a single `<ul>` tag vertical. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

Refer below links:

http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-category-menu-navigation-in-magento/
http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/display-categories-and-subcategories-in-magento/

This might be helpful for your requirement.

Comment: Those tutorials are for multi level categories but I have one single main categories under which I have around 76 categories. I have already tried those and they all displays the categories in a single `<ul>` tag. I am on this forum because I am still a beginner in php and I have tried all I could. I hope you understand my situation.

Comment: Okay, can you please share `level-top` `.phtml` file content in your question?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to do it. You will need test where is your header navigation content coming from.

For instance, in Magento 1.9.2.2 the content comes from: `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml`

**First Approach**

In this file make the below modifications to FOREACH loop ONLY:

```
foreach ($children as $child) {
 $child->setLevel($childLevel);
 $child->setIsFirst($counter == 1);
 $child->setIsLast($counter == $childrenCount);
 $child->setPositionClass($itemPositionClassPrefix . $counter);

 $outermostClassCode = 'level'. $childLevel;
 $_hasChildren = ($child->hasChildren()) ? 'has-children' : '';

$html .= '<ul><li '. $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) .'>';

$html .= '<a href="'. $child->getUrl() .'" class="'. $outermostClassCode .' '. $_hasChildren .'">'. $this->escapeHtml($this->__($child->getName())) .'</a>';

if (!empty($childrenWrapClass)) {
    $html .= '<div class="'. $childrenWrapClass .'">';
}

$nextChildLevel = $childLevel + 1;



if (!empty($childrenWrapClass)) {
    $html .= '</div>';
}

$html .= '</li></ul>';

if (!empty($_hasChildren)) {
    //$html .= '<ul class="level'. $childLevel .'">';
    //$html .=     '<li class="level'. $nextChildLevel .' view-all">';
    //$html .=         '<a class="level'. $nextChildLevel .'" href="'. $child->getUrl() .'">';
    //$html .=             $this->__('View All') . ' ' . $this->escapeHtml($this->__($child->getName()));
    //$html .=         '</a>';
    //$html .=     '</li>';
    $html .=     $this->render($child, $childrenWrapClass);
    //$html .= '</ul>';
}

$counter++;
```

}

Next is to navigate to `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml`:

```
<nav id="nav">
    <?php /*<ol class="nav-primary">*/ ?>
        <?php echo $_menu ?>
    <?php /*</ol>*/ ?>
</nav>
```

The above way you will be able to display each of your categories as required.

**Second Approach**

if your code comes from this file: `app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php`

You will need to override this file: **app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php**

Create the below files:
app/code/local/Namespace/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php
app/code/local/Namespace/Page/etc/config.xml
app/etc/modules/Namespace_Page.xml

Hoping you know what needs to go into which file.

Inside Topmenu.php, copy paste below function:

```
/**
 * Recursively generates top menu html from data that is specified in $menuTree
 *
 * @param Varien_Data_Tree_Node $menuTree
 * @param string $childrenWrapClass
 * @return string
 * @deprecated since 1.8.2.0 use child block catalog.topnav.renderer instead
 */
protected function _getHtml(Varien_Data_Tree_Node $menuTree, $childrenWrapClass)
{
    $html = '';

    $children = $menuTree->getChildren();
    $parentLevel = $menuTree->getLevel();
    $childLevel = is_null($parentLevel) ? 0 : $parentLevel + 1;

    $counter = 1;
    $childrenCount = $children->count();

    $parentPositionClass = $menuTree->getPositionClass();
    $itemPositionClassPrefix = $parentPositionClass ? $parentPositionClass . '-' : 'nav-';

    foreach ($children as $child) {

        $child->setLevel($childLevel);
        $child->setIsFirst($counter == 1);
        $child->setIsLast($counter == $childrenCount);
        $child->setPositionClass($itemPositionClassPrefix . $counter);

        $outermostClassCode = '';
        $outermostClass = $menuTree->getOutermostClass();

        if ($childLevel == 0 && $outermostClass) {
            $outermostClassCode = ' class="' . $outermostClass . '" ';
            $child->setClass($outermostClass);
        }

        $html .= '<ul><li ' . $this->_getRenderedMenuItemAttributes($child) . '>';
        $html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>'
            . $this->escapeHtml($child->getName()) . '</span></a>';

        if ($child->hasChildren()) {
            if (!empty($childrenWrapClass)) {
                $html .= '<div class="' . $childrenWrapClass . '">';
            }
            //$html .= '<ul class="level' . $childLevel . '">';
            $html .= $this->_getHtml($child, $childrenWrapClass);
            //$html .= '</ul>';

            if (!empty($childrenWrapClass)) {
                $html .= '</div>';
            }
        }
        $html .= '</li></ul>';

        $counter++;
    }

    return $html;
}
```

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Happy Coding...